# Hightcharts : columns with custom witdh without custom Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, highcharts

[image]

We are using hightcharts (https://www.highcharts.com/) and we want to do a similar graph but without custom javascript

The graph will be dinamycally generate and the columns will have different width and this is the technical issue we have, we cannot find in highcharts doc a way to implment column with different width without a bit of custom javascript

Do you have any example or any way to do that using tools from highcharts ?

Comment: It's not supported at this moment. See [roadmap](https://www.highcharts.com/support/roadmap) for Highcharts 6: `Variable-width column chart.`.

Comment: One potential method from Highcharts, using a treemap series: http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/h2np93k1/